# How i get media:content url using by XML DOM Parser

Tags: android, parsing, dom

I want parse metia:content tag using by XML DOM Parser.
Here is example:

```
<item>
        <title>AK Saraya tek laf edemeyen yandaş yazardan, lokantaya eleştiri</title>
        <category>Gündem</category>
                <description>&lt;a href=""&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/images/haberler/thumbs2/ak_saraya_tek_laf_edemeyen_yandas_yazardan_lokantaya_elestiri_h11614.jpg" align="left" border="0"  /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;1.4 Milyar Liraya inşa edilen ve özellikle sosyal medyada KAÇAK Saray olarak adlandırılan AK Sarayın maliyeti için tek kelime edemeyen yandaş yazar, hırsını Antepte bulunan bir Restauranttan çıkardı.</description>
                <image>http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/images/haberler/ak_saraya_tek_laf_edemeyen_yandas_yazardan_lokantaya_elestiri_h11614.jpg</image>
        <media:content url="http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/images/haberler/ak_saraya_tek_laf_edemeyen_yandas_yazardan_lokantaya_elestiri_h11614.jpg" type="image/jpeg" medium="image" />
        <media:thumbnail url="http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/images/haberler/ak_saraya_tek_laf_edemeyen_yandas_yazardan_lokantaya_elestiri_h11614.jpg" />
        <enclosure url="http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/images/haberler/ak_saraya_tek_laf_edemeyen_yandas_yazardan_lokantaya_elestiri_h11614.jpg" length="50000" type="image/jpeg" />

                <pubDate>Wed, 12 Nov 2014 00:08:51 +0300</pubDate>



        <link>http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/gundem/ak-saraya-tek-laf-edemeyen-yandas-yazardan-lokantaya-elestiri-h11614.html</link>
        <guid>http://www.onyediyirmibes.com/gundem/ak-saraya-tek-laf-edemeyen-yandas-yazardan-lokantaya-elestiri-h11614.html</guid>
    </item>
```

I can parse title tag like this:

```
NodeList nodeListCountry = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListCountry.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeListCountry.item(i);
                Element elementMain = (Element) node;

                NodeList nodeListText = elementMain
                        .getElementsByTagName("link");
                Element elementText = (Element) nodeListText.item(0);

                list.add(elementText.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

            }
```

How can i parse media:content tag?I need to get image's link for download.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here should be an attribute in the xml like `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`

This defines that element nodes and attributes the alias/prefix `media` are part of the media rss namespace.

Many of the DOM methods have a variant that ends with 'NS' and is namespace aware. For example `getElementsByTagNameNS(String namespaceURI, String localName)`

Usage example:

```
NodeList nodeListMediaContent = elementMain
  .getElementsByTagName("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", "content");
```

*Note*: [Xpath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) is a much easier way to fetch data from an DOM